# Spring data mongodb in clause with case insensitive

Tags: spring-data-mongodb

Is it possible to use IN clause in spring data mongodb with case insensitivity?

For example my `Customer` model have a field `email` and I want to get the list of customers from the list of emails I have.

Normally in JPA, I can get the list of customers from emails using `findAllByEmailIn(List<String> emails)`

I am thinking of setting the emails to lowercase, but this still is not as safe as case insensitive.

Something like:

```
findAllByEmailIn(emails.stream().map(String::toLowerCase).collect(Collectors.toList()))
```

OR

```
    Query query = new Query();
    query.addCriteria(where("email").in(emails.stream()
            .map(String::toLowerCase).collect(Collectors.toList())));
    return m_mongoTemplate.find(query, Customer.class);
```

Is there a way to use IN clause with case insensitivity? Either by JPA findAllBy magic, or by query criterias?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [RegEx](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/)

```
{ email: { $in: [ /^test1@Gmail.Com/i, /^TEST2@gmail.COM/i ] } }
```

Comment: yes, this is another solution but it is not as clean as I expected it to be. With this, I need to alter the emails to convert it into regexp.